# Audit.Net log SOAP client webservice calls

Tags: soap-client, audit.net

My app is uses a third party SOAP webservice.
How do I use Audit.Net to log all the request/response made by my app, the SOAP client?
Similar to Audit.HttpClient extension.

Regards

Comment: That depends on how you make the SOAP calls. Do you create a `WebRequest`, do you use a proxy/service reference? Could you share a sample code?

Comment: The SOAP webservice is added as a connected service which creates the serviceModel binding in web.config. We call the service as such:
`var client = new reportService.ReportPortClient();
var request = new CompanySearchRequest() {
   service = "B2B_ENQ",
   version = "V1.0",
   action = "A",
   clientId = "0",
   uniqueId = "",
   runNo = "",
   totalItems = "1",
   enquiry = enquiry};
var  response = client.CompanySearch(request);`

Comment: I guess you could use `Audit.DynamicProxy` like this `var client = AuditProxy.Create<IReportPortClient>(new reportService.ReportPortClient());`

Comment: The generated class for ReportPortClient is
`public partial class ReportPortClient : System.ServiceModel.ClientBase<ReportPort>, ReportPort { ... }
`
Tried creating the AuditProxy as 
`var client = AuditProxy.Create<ReportPort>(new ReportPortClient());
...
  var request = new CompanySearchRequest() { ... }
  var response = client.CompanySearch(request);
`
But hit an issue where interface is not same as class CompanySearch.

Comment: The ReportPortClient.CompanySearch() function 
`public CompanySearchResponse CompanySearch( ReportService.CompanySearchRequest CompanySearchRequest) {
    CompanySearchRequest1 inValue = new CompanySearchRequest1();
    inValue.CompanySearchRequest = CompanySearchRequest;
    CompanySearchResponse1 retVal = ((ReportPort)(this)).CompanySearch(inValue);
    return retVal.CompanySearchResponse;
        }
`

Comment: Instead of interface, tried with the instance.
`var proxy = AuditProxy.Create<ReportPortClient>(client);`
But the capture event is  CreateChannel instead of CompanySearch
`{
  "EventType": "ReportPortClient.CreateChannel",
  "Environment": {...},
  "StartDate": "2021-07-17T16:51:21.8427382Z",
  "EndDate": "2021-07-17T16:51:21.964177Z",
  "Duration": 121,
  "InterceptEvent": {
    "ClassName": "ReportPortClient",
    "MethodName": "CreateChannel",
...   
 "Success": true,
    "Result": {
      "Type": "ReportPort",
      "Value": {}
    }
  }
}`

Answer (score 0):

One option could be to use [Audit.DynamicProxy](https://github.com/thepirat000/Audit.NET/blob/master/src/Audit.DynamicProxy/README.md) to intercept the proxy calls, so for example if you use the `ChannelFactory` to create the proxy, you could do the following:

```cs
using Audit.DynamicProxy;

public T CreateProxy<T>(Uri uri, HttpBindingBase binding)
{
    var channelFactory = new ChannelFactory<T>(binding, new EndpointAddress(uri));
    return AuditProxy.Create<T>(channelFactory.CreateChannel());
}
```

Then when you do a service call, for example:

```cs
var proxy = CreateProxy<ICatalogService>(uri, binding);
var product = proxy.GetDetailedProductInfo(new GetDetailedProductInfoRequest() { ProductId = "1234" };
```

You should get an audit event with format similar to:

```js
{
    "EventType": "generatedProxy_1.GetDetailedProductInfo",
    "Environment": {
        ...
    },
    "StartDate": "2021-07-16T19:48:15.294298Z",
    "EndDate": "2021-07-16T19:48:21.6566853Z",
    "Duration": 6362,
    "InterceptEvent": {
        "ClassName": "generatedProxy_1",
        "MethodName": "GetDetailedProductInfo",
        "IsAsync": false,
        "InstanceQualifiedName": "generatedProxy_1, ProxyBuilder, Version=0.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null",
        "MethodSignature": "CatalogService.GetDetailedProductInfoResponse GetDetailedProductInfo(CatalogService.GetDetailedProductInfoRequest)",
        "Arguments": [
            {
                "Index": 0,
                "Type": "GetDetailedProductInfoRequest",
                "Value": {
                    "request": {
                        "ProductId": "1234"
                    }
                }
            }
        ],
        "Success": true,
        "Result": {
            "Type": "GetDetailedProductInfoResponse",
            "Value": {
                "GetDetailedProductInfoResult": {
                    "Product": {
                        "ProductId": "1234",
                        "Description": "Some description".
                        "CreationDate": "2007-10-31T11:30:35-06:00"
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Wonder if I can implement the IClientMessageInspector.
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/wcf/extending/how-to-inspect-or-modify-messages-on-the-client
In this case, where should I create the AuditScope? within BeforeSendRequest() function?

Comment: @hcchoi You're right. I think that's the way to go. Actually [Audit.Wcf](https://github.com/thepirat000/Audit.NET/tree/master/src/Audit.WCF) library implements a `IOperationBehavior` but only for the server side, I think I could add the client side option for the new version. In the meantime you could check how it's implemented [here](https://github.com/thepirat000/Audit.NET/blob/master/src/Audit.WCF/AuditOperationInvoker.cs). Basically you should create the `AuditScope` before making the call, then update the results of the call to the `AuditEvent` for that scope, and then dispose the scope.

Comment: Just opened https://github.com/thepirat000/Audit.NET/issues/427 to track this

Answer (score 0):

You can now use the extension library [`Audit.WCF.Client`](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Audit.WCF.Client/) which allows auditing client-side WCF service calls.

Please check the documentation [here](https://github.com/thepirat000/Audit.NET/blob/master/src/Audit.WCF.Client/README.md).

It's basically an [`IClientMessageInspector`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.servicemodel.dispatcher.iclientmessageinspector?view=dotnet-plat-ext-5.0) that intercepts the request and response messages.